# Modal Popup from CEWP

Tags: error, popup

I need some help.  I'm very new to SharePoint development so please go easy on me.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

- I need a Modal window to popup during page load of home.aspx to display a disclaimer with an "I Agree" button.
- What I have so far is that while editing the CEWP it will popup everytime and close properly with the button but only while in edit mode.
- Once I click OK and go back to the public shared view, it throws an error referencing SP.UI.ModalDialog.
- SP.UI.ModalDialog is not a file on our SP2010 server.

Here is the code I'm using in the CEWP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function codeAddress() {
    var options = {
         url: "http://devspf01/disclaimer.aspx" };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("codeAddress");</script>
```

This is the line it errors on:
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Bg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharePoint 2010: JavaScript error when creating Modal Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272753/sharepoint-2010-javascript-error-when-creating-modal-dialog)

Use [ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff411788(v=office.14).aspx), to make sure it executes after sp.js is loaded!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function codeAddress() {

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        var options = {
            url: "http://devspf01/disclaimer.aspx" };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
     }, 'sp.js');
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("codeAddress");</script>
```